# Variables aren't getting updated with the proper values

Tags: java

I'm making a java program for the system used at Luas Station to purchase tickets. The Luas is a type of train in the Ireland.

I have a few different types of tickets which involves various prices etc. After a customer selects what ticket to buy I give them an option to return to the beginning of the 'chooseTickets' to buy more tickets. At the end, the program I have assigned the value of all of the customer's desired tickets as the completePrice variable. the idea is to allow for the customer to continue adding tickets and for that variable to continuously add the prices of them to the variable until they're ready to pay. It works except when I go back to purchase for tickets and it is the same type, i.e a standard adult ticket twice. The price of 2.50 is not added to another 2.50, it is overwritten by another 2.5. Below is the code for the same:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //imports the scanner class to allow for user input

public class ticketPurchase {
//Adding global variables to be used by various methods
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String menuChoice;
static double childTicket = 1.20;
static double adultTicket = 2.50;
static double studentTicket = 1.70;
static double adultFlexi = 12.00;
static double childFlexi = 8.00;
static double studentFlexi;
static String ticketType;
static String ticketChoice;
static int adultTicketQty;
static int childTicketQty;
static int studentTicketQty;
static String destinationZone;
static double adultFinalPrice;
static double childFinalPrice;
static double studentFinalPrice;
static double flexiAdultFinalPrice;
static double flexiChildFinalPrice;
static double completePrice;
static String moreTicketChoice2 = "0";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu(); //calling the menu method within the main method to start the process
}
public static void menu() {
    if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")){
        System.out.println("Press 2 to purchase Standard Tickets");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to purchase Flexi tickets");
        System.out.println("press 4 to purchase student tickets");
    }
    else if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("0")) {
        System.out.println("Press 1 for information");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to purchase Standard Tickets");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to purchase Flexi tickets");
        System.out.println("press 4 to purchase student tickets");
    }
    menuChoice = input.next(); //allowing user to choose what tickets to buy or just to see information of services

    switch(menuChoice) { //switch statement to record and output information based on users input
    case "1":{ //prints information regarding pricing, ticket age restrictions and support
        System.out.println("The standard ticket may be a single or return ticket for an adult (16+) or a child");
        System.out.println("The flexi ticket covers all journeys for one 24 hour period for either a child or an adult");
        System.out.println("A single ticket's price depends on the journey length, single or return and if it is for an adult or a child");
        System.out.println("a Flexi ticket for a child costs €8.00 and a Flexi ticket for an adult costs €12.00");
        System.out.println("Our Customer Care telephone number for this terminal is 0830462920, please call if further support is required");
        menu();
        break;
    }
    case "2":{
        ticketChoice = "standard"; //records the value of standard within the ticketChoice global variable
        chooseTickets(); //initiates the choose tickets method
        break;
    }
    case "3":{
        ticketChoice = "flexi"; //record the value of Flexi within the ticketChoice global variable
        chooseTickets(); 
        break;
    }
    case "4":{
        ticketChoice = "student";
        chooseTickets();
    }
    case "a":{ //allows user to enter the admin interface 
        admin();
        break;
    }
    default:{ //allows for user to input a value outside of the options and notify's them to try again
        System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose from 1 to 3");
        break;
    }
    }

}
public static void chooseTickets() { //payment method to choose quantity, destination zone and final price
    System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketChoice + " ticket(s)");
    if(ticketChoice.equals("student")) { //allows user to purchase student's tickets
        ticketType = "student";
        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
        studentTicketQty = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
        destinationZone = input.next();
        ticketChoice = "student"; 
            studentFinalPrice = (studentTicket*studentTicketQty);
        switch(destinationZone){ //adjusts price to account for the destination's zone chosen by user
        case "1":{
            studentFinalPrice = studentFinalPrice + (studentTicketQty*0);
            break;
        }
        case "2":{
            studentFinalPrice = studentFinalPrice + (studentTicketQty*0.50);
            break;
        }
        case "3":{
            studentFinalPrice = studentFinalPrice + (studentTicketQty*1.0);
            break;
        }
        case "4":{
            studentFinalPrice = studentFinalPrice + (studentTicketQty*1.50);
            break;
        }
        default:{
            System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
            chooseTickets();
            break;
        }
        }
        System.out.print("would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets 
        moreTicketChoice2 = input.next();
        if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")) {
            menu();
        }
        else if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("2")){
            System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
            payment();
        }


    }
    else {
        System.out.print("please enter 1 for children's tickets and 2 for adult's: ");
        String ticketAgeGroup = input.next();
        switch(ticketAgeGroup) { //allows user to choose quantity and destination based on choice of adult or child
        case "2":{//case for adult tickets
            System.out.println("you have chosen adults ticket");
            ticketType = "adult";
            System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
            adultTicketQty = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
            destinationZone = input.next();
            if(ticketChoice == "flexi") { //if statement to calculate the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is Flexi
                flexiAdultFinalPrice = (adultFlexi*adultTicketQty);
            }
            else {
                adultFinalPrice = (adultTicket*adultTicketQty); //else calculates the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is standard
            }
            switch(destinationZone){ // switch statement to calculate the final price depending on the destination's zone and their extra amount.
            case "1":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*0); 
                break;
            }
            case "2":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*.50); //calculation to add the extra amount for the destination
                break;
            }
            case "3":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.0);
                break;
            }
            case "4":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.50);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                break;
            }
            } //end of the switch statement

            System.out.print("Would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets 
            moreTicketChoice2 = input.next();
            if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")) { //if statement to allow a customer to purchase more tickets if required
                menu();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
                payment(); //proceeds to the payment method
            }


            break;
        }

        case "1":{ //case for children's tickets
            System.out.println("you have chosen children's ticket");
            ticketType = "child";
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
            childTicketQty = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
            destinationZone = input.next();
            if(ticketChoice == "flexi") { //adjusts the price if user chooses the flexi option 
                flexiChildFinalPrice = (childFlexi*childTicketQty);
            }
            else {
                childFinalPrice = (childTicket*childTicketQty);
            }
            switch(destinationZone){ //adjusts price to account for the destination's zone chosen by user
            case "1":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*0);
                break;
            }
            case "2":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*.50);
                break;
            }
            case "3":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.0);
                break;
            }
            case "4":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.50);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                chooseTickets();
                break;
            }
            }

            System.out.print("would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets 
            moreTicketChoice2 = input.next();
            if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")) {
                menu();
            }
            else if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("2")){
                System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
                payment();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    }
public static void payment() { //method to complete the payment process for the purchase
    completePrice = adultFinalPrice + childFinalPrice + studentFinalPrice + flexiAdultFinalPrice + flexiChildFinalPrice;
    System.out.println("the total due is €" + completePrice);


}
public static void printTickets() { //method to notify the customer that their tickets are printing 

}
public static void admin() { //method to control the admin's interface

}
```

}

[In this photo i want an output of 2.4 not 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD1Nf.png)

Comment: `if anyone could look through my code and make any suggestions i would really appreciate it.` What code?

Comment: sorry! added it now

Comment: Are you asking why `adultFinalPrice = (adultTicket*adultTicketQty);` overwrites `adultFinalPrice`?

Comment: I think you wanted `adultFinalPrice += (adultTicket*adultTicketQty);`

Comment: at the end of my program i want it to output the price of all the tickets being purchased, to do that i need to have all of the instances of different types of tickets adding to each variable each time the user goes back and purchases another ticket that is the same, ive attached a photo that shows how the output is incorrect

Comment: It's suggested that you don't dump your entire program here. Only enough to show a [mcve] of the specific problem you're having (remove the menu, isolate the switch cases, etc)

Comment: Plus, calling a method within itself is a bad habit to repeat something, use a proper while loop, then `ticketChoice == "flexi"` isn't how to compare strings... Other than that, might be a good idea to follow a tutorial on using a debugger in your favorite IDE

Comment: okay thank you i've changed that to if(ticketChoice.equals("flexi")), im not 100% sure where in my program would be appropriate for a while loop but i will do some research. as for my original question i can't find much help online so if anyone can help please do :)